# In batch my menu will not work

Tags: batch-file, input

I was trying to create a simple menu system with batch but i can't tell if it's the 'goto' or the input part that i messed up on. help will be appreciated!

```
@echo off
cls


echo ==============MENU==============
echo 1.
echo 2.
echo 3.

echo choose.
set/p "menuInput"



if %menuInput%==1 (goto :1)
if %menuInput%==2 (goto :2)
if %menuInput%==3 (goto :3)
else echo error
:1 echo 1
:2 echo 2
:3 echo 3
```

Comment: There is the equal-to sign missing: `set /P menuInput=` (no need for quotation). Do not place a space between the variable name and the `=` as it becomes part of the name then!

Answer (score 0):

1. The syntax of `set /p` is incorrect. Use `set /?` to read the help.
2. The parentheses around `(goto :1)` don't buy you anything.
3. The `else` is both syntactically incorrect (must be on the same logical line as the `if`) and useless (because if the `if` had succeeded control would have been passed to `:3`).
4. You are missing a bunch of `exit /b` or `goto :eof` in order to prevent control falling through the options.

Answer (score 0):

ok i updated your code now this shold work

code here

```
@echo off
:menu
cls
title menu 
echo ==============MENU==============
echo 1.
echo 2.
echo 3.
set /p menuInput=? 1-3
if %menuInput% EQU 1 goto 1
if %menuInput% EQU 2 goto 2
if %menuInput% EQU 3 goto 3
goto error
:1 
echo1
pause
:2 
echo2
pause
:3 
echo3
pause
:error
echo error press 1-3
pause>nul
goto menu
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by *@AlexP*,your *syntax* of `set /p` is incorrect

you need to use **`set`** < space > **/p** < space >  userinput=

and not `set/p` and there should be `=` sign after your `variable` name

**`SET /P variable=[promptString]`**

**Read More about using [SET](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) & [IF ELSE](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) and also [CHOICE](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html)**

*(edit- removed misleading code for error check)*

sample batch with menu using `Choice` and `SET /P` `IF Else` while choosing option from menu.

> **Example 1 using IF ELSE (input error check)**

```
@echo off

::Your Menu to choose from
:menu
cls
echo ==============MENU==============
echo 1.command menu item 1
echo 2.command menu item 2
echo 3.command menu item 3
echo.

set /p userinput=

if %userinput%==1 (
goto 1
) else if %userinput%==2 (
goto 2
) else if %userinput%==3 (
goto 3
) else (
goto error
)

:1
echo command 1
pause>nul
goto menu
:2
echo command 2
pause>nul
goto menu
:3
echo command 3
pause>nul
goto menu

::Incorrect Input go back to menu
:error
echo Incorrect User Input
pause>nul
goto menu
:end
exit
```

> **Example 2 using CHOICE command** ***(no error input check)***

```
@echo off

::Your Menu to choose from

:menu
cls
echo ==============MENU==============
echo 1.command menu item 1
echo 2.command menu item 2
echo 3.command menu item 3

::check and limit user input to selection
choice /C 123 /N /M "Your Selection"

IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" goto 1
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="2" goto 2
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3" goto 3

:1
echo command 1
pause>nul
goto menu
:2
echo command 2
pause>nul
goto menu
:3
echo command 3
pause>nul
goto menu
```

Comment: In my experience there's nothing at all wrong with using `Set/P`, _there is no need to follow `Set` with whitespace when using an option/parameter_.

Comment: Your logic is wrong; it correctly process just option 1 and mark an error in any other case. Also, it have no sense to include the /i switch in IF command when comparing digits (there are not upcase/lowcase digits...)

Answer (score -3):

Wrong is set /p.

try  `set /p menuInput =`

Comment: That's wrong syntax! Type `set /?` into a command prompt window and read the help very carefully!